# React-Native static class properties: A semicolon is required after a class property

Tags: react-native

Since this morning I'm having this issue when starting a React-Native server:

```
transforming [========================================] 100% 613/614Error while persisting cache: SyntaxError /Users/matteo/dev/react-native-starter/src/containers/login.js: A semicolon is required after a class property (24:3)
```

The code:

```js
class LoginModal extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.string,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  } // <-- needs semicolon now
```

My .babelrc

```js
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

You can also see the complete repo here [here](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-starter).
I'm having this issue after an `npm install`I did this morning, I didn't change the code at all.
I already tried deleting the npm cache/node_modules and starting the packager with `--reset-cache`, without any success.
Anyone else having the same issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It comes from a Babel update that happened in a RN update (0.19 if I recall).

Anyways, you have to add a semicolon now, or downgrade RN which I don't recommend. What happened is you upgraded RN when doing an `npm install`

Comment: I remember that issue but [they fixed it after a few days](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5188#issuecomment-193276387) :(